# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}))$ convergence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Check if the following series converge or diverge:$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}))$

I have tried the integral test since the series are decreasing to zero as $n\to\infty$, but $\int_1^\infty 1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) dn=n-\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})|_0^\infty$, which diverges.
I am not seeing what test could I applied that would deliver me the desired result convergence, since the book solution states that the series converge.

**Question**:

What do you think of the series? What test shall I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $\int 1 - \cos(\pi /x){\rm d}x$ is not $x - \sin(\pi/x)$. The integral actually converges. Also note that if this was correct then it would have proven that the series diverges.

Comment: @Winther What is the integral? How does it converge then?

Comment: It's a non elementary function (try plugging it into WA to see it - to see its wrong just take the derivative of what you got and see you don't get the integrand back). It converges because the integrated behaves as $C/n^2$ for large  $n $ just as the sum does and the integral of this converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}\in(0,+\infty).$$